# yum update failed "StopIteration" hdr = idx.next()

Tags: python, centos, yum, cloudera-quickstart-vm

Just trying a routine `yup update`

And first got this:

```
...
  Cleanup    : ncurses-base-5.7-3.20090208.el6.x86_64                                                                                                                                         553/554 
  Cleanup    : libgcc-4.4.7-16.el6.x86_64                                                                                                                                                     554/554 

Rpmdb checksum is invalid: dCDPT(pkg checksums): glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.12-1.212.el6 - u
```

Running `yum update` again:

```
error: db3 error(-30986) from dbcursor->c_get: DB_PAGE_NOTFOUND: Requested page not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 29, in <module>
    yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 298, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 115, in main
    base.getOptionsConfig(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 229, in getOptionsConfig
    self.conf
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 911, in <lambda>
    conf = property(fget=lambda self: self._getConfig(),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 300, in _getConfig
    startupconf = config.readStartupConfig(fn, root)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/config.py", line 896, in readStartupConfig
    startupconf.releasever = _getsysver(startupconf.installroot, startupconf.distroverpkg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/config.py", line 1047, in _getsysver
    hdr = idx.next()
StopIteration
```

Running next what was recommended at:
https://www.redhat.com/archives/rhl-list/2006-November/msg05907.html

> rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__* ; rpm -vv --rebuilddb

```
D: rebuilding database /var/lib/rpm into /var/lib/rpmrebuilddb.15483
D: creating directory /var/lib/rpmrebuilddb.15483
D: opening old database with dbapi 3
D: opening  db environment /var/lib/rpm create:cdb:mpool:joinenv
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages rdonly mode=0x0
D: locked   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages
D: opening new database with dbapi 3
D: opening  db environment /var/lib/rpmrebuilddb.15483 create:mpool:joinenv
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpmrebuilddb.15483/Packages create mode=0x42
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages
D: closed   db environment /var/lib/rpm
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpmrebuilddb.15483/Packages
D: closed   db environment /var/lib/rpmrebuilddb.15483
D: removing directory /var/lib/rpmrebuilddb.15483
$yum update
Traceback (most recent call last): (same stack trace)
```

This is a Centos Cloudera Quickstart docker container spun from cloudera/quickstart:latest

```
CentOS release 6.10 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's what worked for me:

1. stop, remove and restart the container

> $ docker stop cloudera_1
>
> $ docker rm cloudera_1
>
> $ docker run --hostname=quickstart.cloudera
>   --privileged=true -t -i -p 0.0.0.0:8888:8888 --name cloudera_1 cloudera/quickstart /usr/bin/docker-quickstart

2. install yum overlay path and update python, according to [xavierbaude](https://github.com/CentOS/sig-cloud-instance-images/issues/15)

> $ yum install -y yum-plugin-ovl
>
> $ yum update -y python

3. update yum

> $ yum update -y